# xcode, macbook and copy buffer pushed into iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, clipboard

I have a situation, trivial but very interesting. I have a string copied into the clipboard on my mac, coding in Xcode, running an app on my device, testing a project. Hit a breakpoint. I had my phone's clipboard saving my login name to save repeatedly tapping that in to test a login screen on my device.

Just ran the app, and went to paste, and the string from my MacBook magically appears as the pasteable text on my phone.

I have never seen that before. Is this a "feature" i am unaware of?
{edit: embarrassingly simple answer, left for somebody else not to be so noob .. }

Answer (score 1):

In the Edit menu of the Simulator turn off *Automatically sync pasteboard*
[image]

Comment: Thanks Paul. Amazing that I’ve never noticed this before.